# Reverse polarity protection circuit consumption

Tags: current, pnp, reverse-polarity

I found this reverse polarity circuit that uses a matched PNP pair and a MOSFET: https://projects-raspberry.com/raspberry-pi-b-power-protection-circuit/

I tested this circuit and with no load i get around 270uA of quiescent current when connected in direct polarity. That current is to high since i want to protect a battery operated circuit.

So i changed the 47k resistors for 1M resistors and i got around 15uA of current consumption. I reverse the polarity and the circuit blocked it, so it seems it still works.

My questions are:

1. Is it ok to use 1M resistors instead of 47K? any caveat?
2. any other ideas to lower current consumption?

Thanks

Comment: First time I saw this "ideal diode" circuit, it had 100k on the left and 65k on the right.  So it can tolerate a lot of variation.  Probably has to do with performance behaviors that the designer wants.  ie. how fast you want it to switch.

Comment: Also note, that the circuit as shown can only be used up to about 5V in reverse bias direction before Vbe of the BJT breaks down.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron for your response. 
So max Vbe will limit the reverse voltage protection, right? I was looking something up to 12V

Comment: This circuit fixes the Vbe breakdown issue: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/simple-inexpensive-ideal-diode-mosfet-circuits.817/

Comment: Great, thanks, i'll try that.
Just another question: in direct polarity, just Q1 is ON, so to reduce quiescent current i just need to have a high R1 value and keep R2 as original value right? I want to reduce quiescent current but keep circuit fast enough if reverse polarity occurs

Comment: I think LTSpice is the way to go to answer those questions.  Only you know what fast enough is.